# How can I use IP address (via InetAddress) to establish a connection with MySQL via JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package inventory;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

/**
 *
 * @author Imantha
 */
public class dbcon {

  public static Connection createmyConnection() throws Exception{

    InetAddress ip=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    String s=ip.getHostAddress();
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localHost:3306/inventory","root","123");   
    return c;
 }
}
```

*How can i use ip addre which find from using InerAddress  for connect with MySQL via JDBC?*

I want to replace local host and add s(which catch ip address)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You don't need to use `InetAddress` with JDBC. You just need to construct a correct JDBC URL.

You also haven't needed the `Class.forName()` line since 2007.

Answer (score 0):

If only replacing it what you want, then

```
Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+s+"/inventory","root","123");
```

Just change the connection URL to take IP address which is stored in variable `s`